# Решение классической комбинаторной задачи на нахождение всех вариантов перестановок цифр для заданного числа

Tags: c#, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Здравствуйте. Помогите с решением задачи.

> реализовать алгоритм выплаты заданной суммы всеми возможными способами. В наличии есть купюры стоимостью 1,2,5,10,20,50,100 рублей. Количество каждого вида не ограничено.

Это все делается как-то рекурсивно. У меня получилось сделать только в заданном порядке, как сделать алгоритм для всех вариантов - не могу понять. ПОМОГИТЕ !

Если можно, код на c#.

Пример моего алгоритма с заданным порядком:

```
class Class1
{

    private int num;

    public void get(int a) {

        num = a;

        func();

    }

    private void func() {

        int[] mas = { 100, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1 };
        int[] mas2 = new int[1000];

        int res = 0, j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++ ) {

            res += mas[i];
            mas2[j] = mas[i]; j++;

            if (res == num) break;

            if (num > res) {

                while (num > res)
                {
                    mas2[j] = mas[i]; j++;
                    res += mas[i];

                }

            }

            if (num < res) { res -= mas[i]; j--; }

        }

        string dot;
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
        {
            if ((k + 1) == j) { dot = ""; } else { dot = ","; }
            Console.Write(mas2[k] + dot);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Сумму в N рублей можно заплатить с использованием купюры в 100 рублей или без использования купюры в 100 рублей: F(N,{1,2,5,10,20,50,100})=F(N-100,{1,2,5,10,20,50,100})+F(N,{1,2,5,10,20,50}).

Comment: «ПОМОГИТЕ» означает «я хочу научиться», а не «напишите код за меня».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я писал тестовое задание однажды, нужен был тот же алгоритм. Можно посмотреть  [вот здесь](https://bitbucket.org/pavelhritonenko/vendingmachine/src/818b7757a5442a1cc698a691c1d7e011af957d0c/VendingMachine/Bag.fs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#Bag.fs-28:43).

Answer (score 1):

1.Делаете структуру (словарь, список) для хранения всех способов оплаты каждого номинала купюры назовем ее payment_dictonary.

2.Делаем функцию для декартова произведения двух таких структур(dmult)

3.Делаем вторую функцию для получения списка оплаты суммы <= максимального номинала(100), ее тоже можно сделать рекурсивно, кстати. (base_payment_option)

4.Делаем рекурсивную функцию(как так):

```
<Ваша структура> payment_option(unsigned int sum)
{
    if (sum == 0) return new <Ваша структура>(); //пустая
    if (sum < 100)
    {
        return base_payment_option(sum);
    }
    else
    {
        return(dmult(payment_option(sum - 100), payment_dictonary[100]);
    }
}
```

**UPD** Декартово произведение растет очень и очень быстро, поэтому на крупных суммах ваша структура вполне способна забить всю наличную память (и оперативную и постоянную, зависит от суммы) вашего компьютера. Если нужны большие суммы, я бы искал не рекурсивный а итеративный алгоритм, на каждой итерации данные куда нибудь выводил, и очищал память.